# C preprocessor defines not taken into account by Cedet/Semantic

Tags: linux, emacs, linux-kernel, preprocessor, emacs-semantic

I am trying to use Emacs as an IDE in my Linux kernel development projects. So I installed CEDET and GNU Global (gtags) with no problems.

When I open a C source code belonging to my Linux kernel source folder, the linux project is detected automatically. Functions, variables, headers and other keywords are highlighted correctly.

Through the ~/.emacs file I configured semantic's code completion and intellisense. So when I press C- the code completion menu appears and I can choose what's needed.

The issue is when I use preprocessor defines, the intellisense system shows the menu on the current location but doesn't detect the right things when invoked (C-). Even I close and restart emacs the same behavior is reproduced.

The test code is:

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
typedef struct
{
     int p1;

        #ifdef __KERNEL__

            int p2;

        #endif

        #ifdef USE1

             char p3;

          #endif

#ifdef __LINUX_ARM_ARCH__

   int p4;

#endif

}OBJ;

OBJ g_obj;
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**KERNEL** , USE1 and **LINUX_ARM_ARCH** are already defined as follows:

```
__KERNEL__ : (add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-map '("__KERNEL__" . "")) in .emacs
USE1 : defined in a header file included by the current C source file.
__LINUX_ARM_ARCH__ : (add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file "/home/abdellatif/kernel/include/generated/autoconf.h") in .emacs
```

In the .emacs file I also added all the needed includes and defines required by GCC cross compiler (GCC for ARM) to build the kernel project.

I also tried to force semantic to use GCC cross compiler command line in place of the system GCC to preprocess correctly but haven't found how to do that.

The "M-x semantic-c-describe-environment" command shows the right include paths and defines
 (set in .emacs). But the system GCC defines are also listed.

The .emacs file and the software versions are shown below.

Any help or indication is welcomed :)
Best regards

```
############# Software versions #############

- Emacs (23.2.1)
- Ubuntu machine (natty, 11.04)
- Cedet 1.0 (from http://cedet.sourceforge.net/)
```

```
############# .emacs #############

;load CEDET

(load-file "~/Documents/my_emacs/cedet-1.0/common/cedet.el")

(require 'ede)

(global-ede-mode t)
; turn on which-func support (plus all other code helpers)
(semantic-load-enable-gaudy-code-helpers)
(semantic-load-enable-excessive-code-helpers)

; turn on all "useful" features
(setq semantic-load-turn-useful-things-on t)

(setq-mode-local c-mode
         semanticdb-find-default-throttle
         '(project unloaded system recursive))

;init names completion, and displaying of information for tags & classes
(require 'semantic-ia)

;preprocessing of source code

(require 'semantic-c)

(semantic-reset-system-include 'c-mode)
(semantic-reset-system-include 'c++-mode)
(semantic-add-system-include "/home/abdellatif/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.3/include" 'c-mode)
(semantic-add-system-include "/home/abdellatif/kernel/arch/arm/include" 'c-mode)
(semantic-add-system-include "/home/abdellatif/kernel/include" 'c-mode)
(semantic-add-system-include "/home/abdellatif/kernel/arch/arm/mach-omap2/include" 'c-mode)
(semantic-add-system-include "/home/abdellatif/kernel/arch/arm/plat-omap/include" 'c-mode)
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file "/home/abdellatif/kernel/include/generated/autoconf.h")
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-map '("__KERNEL__" . ""))
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-map '("__LINUX_ARM_ARCH__" . "7"))
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-map '("KBUILD_STR(s)" . "#s"))
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-map '("KBUILD_BASENAME" . "KBUILD_STR(main)"))
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-map '("KBUILD_MODNAME" . "KBUILD_STR(main)"))

;semantic integration with imenu (display of a menu with a list of functions, variables, and other tags)
(defun my-semantic-hook ()
  (imenu-add-to-menubar "TAGS"))
(add-hook 'semantic-init-hooks 'my-semantic-hook)

;names completion (semantic commands)
(defun my-cedet-hook ()
 (local-set-key [(control return)] 'semantic-ia-complete-symbol)
  (local-set-key "\C-x " 'semantic-ia-complete-symbol-menu)
   (local-set-key "\C-x\r" 'gtags-find-tag-from-here))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-cedet-hook)

;navigating in source code
(semantic-mru-bookmark-mode 1)

;tell semantic to store its tags database between sessions here
(require 'semanticdb)
(setq-default semanticdb-default-save-directory "~/.semantic.cache")
(setq-default semanticdb-default-system-save-directory "~/.semantic.cache")

;allow Semanticdb use databases generated by global(gtags)
(require 'semanticdb-global)
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c-mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should get cedet from mainline:
   `bzr://cedet.bzr.sourceforge.net/bzrroot/cedet/code/trunk/`
   there were several fixes for preprocessor handling recently.
2. After changing the list of semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file and similar
   stuff, you should remove semantic cache and allow it recreate it from scratch.